# How to predict address space layout differences between real and gdb-controlled executions?

Tags: gdb, memory

It's something that puzzle me for a long time. I can observe that there is a difference between the real execution of a program and the `gdb`-controlled one.

But, here is an example:

1. First, here is the example code (we use an automatic variable to get the location of the stack):

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main ()
   {
     char c = 0;

     printf ("Stack address: %p\n", &c);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
2. Then, we disable the ASLR (we use the personality flags of the process and not the system-wide method through `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`):

   ```
   $> setarch `uname -m` -R /bin/bash
   ```
3. Then, get a run in the real memory environment:

   ```
   Stack address: 0x7fffffffe1df
   ```
4. And, the same through `gdb`:

   ```
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: ./gdb-against-reality
    Stack address: 0x7fffffffe17f
    [Inferior 1 (process 5374) exited normally]
    (gdb)
   ```

So, here we have a difference of 96 bytes between the two runs. But, how can I predict this difference for a given program without having it running in the *real* memory layout (just by knowing the `gdb` memory layout) ?

And, also, from where/what is coming this difference ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There could be other factors involved, but my guess would be that changes in the process environment variables, which are stored on the stack, are what's causing this issue.

Running a small [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c) that just prints out the environment variables reveals a couple variations in environment variables when run inside vs outside gdb on my system.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)
{
  char** env;
  for (env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
  {
    char* thisEnv = *env;
    printf("%s\n", thisEnv);    
  }
}
```

First, when running under gdb, there is a LINES variable that isn't present when the process is started outside of gdb:

```
LINES=83
```

Secondly, the underscore environment variable is different. When running outside of gdb, it is set to the name of the executable:

```
_=./gdbtest
```

But when started from inside gdb, it is set to the path of the gdb binary:

```
_=/usr/bin/gdb
```

You can try to run the program normally, then attach to it with gdb/gdbserver, which should avoid these variations in environment variables (assuming that is in fact what is causing your problem).

If your process is short-lived, it can be hard to pause the process before it exits. Maybe someone else has some good suggestions on starting a process in a paused state; I usually use a second program like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/botox/source/browse/trunk/src/botox.c) to catch the process as it is starting and pause it so I can attach a debugger to it.

Comment: This answer on stackoverflow shows how to run gdb with a controlled environment https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775966. You can simply use his script (remember to run `unset` commands inside `gdb`)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the answers, I can tell how to get close to a clean environment despite `gdb`. In fact, there are two methods to reach this:

1. We can get rid of the extra environment variables added by `gdb` as follow:

   ```
   (gdb) unset environment LINES
   (gdb) unset environment COLUMNS
   ```

   Write these commands before running the program, and you should be close to the normal environment. Note that you still have to take care of the `_` variable.
2. One can also generate a memory core of the vulnerable program and analyze it with `gdb`:

   ```
   $> gdb vuln_program core
   ```

   You should just look at the memory and never `run`, `next`, `step`, ... because doing so will force you to restart the program with a fresh memory (with the shift).

That was two methods you can use with `gdb` to follow a program without too much differences with the real execution. But, they are many others!